# Connect my mobile phone as modem?

Tags: networking, internet, smartphone, tethering

I have mobile phone "Sony Ericsson C510", i can connect the phone via cable as modem and through Windows7 i can make it connect to internet via phone connection.
Can i do that in Ubuntu?
notice my phone have option when i connect them called "Other OS E.g Mac, Linux"

Comment: Can't you see somewhere (on your phone, Windows, manual, ...) what protocol it uses to connect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the phone is supported as-is (which it should be, given that other people [tried the same thing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1146395) a while ago, when you connect the phone it should be possible to configure it as a modem.

It's possible that Network Manager will detect the phone, and give you an option when you left-click on its icon in the system tray. Otherwise, you could try right-clicking, click "edit connections", choose the "mobile broadband" tab, and click Add. If your phone has been detected it will show up in the list, then you just need to enter the settings specific to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure the phone Connection type, set it to Data Connection. THe phone will be detected as a Mobile Broadband Device. Then right click the Connections, browse to the mobile connection, edit it, and enter the username and password.